# how to make a child and Parent class by the given information?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, get, polymorphism

I have been told to make a Satellite class, which is the parent class of the Moon and an artificial satellite. Extra information ( Satellites orbit planets, and Planets have zero or more Satellites). This is the only information that I was given. So I looked for a format for the parent and child classes. This was the result of what I found.

Format:

class Child: public Parent{};

By following this logic. Is this correct?

Class Moon: public satellites {

};

The given code above is what I came up with by following the format. However, I have a feeling that this doesn't seem right. Your guidance on this matter will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Strange.. before giving an assignment to create parent/child classes, I would expect that the instructor or teacher will go over the appropriate C++ syntax for doing so. There would be no need to "looked for" how to do that; sounds like you have a bad C++ instructor that does not explain the taught material, before handing out assignments.

Comment: Blaming the professor out of the gate with nothing more than a second-hand account of what the requirements are and no knowledge of what material has been taught is a bold assumption. Judging by the content of *this* post alone, the student might have missed or not paid attention when inheritance was covered. Many students don't seem to think that lecture and assignments have any meaningful connection.

Answer (score 1):

Your c in Class should be lowercase, and s in satellites should be uppercase.

```
class Moon: public Satellites{};
```

For more information about class rule in c++ you can read it [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class)

Comment: Uppercase class names isn't a rule. Important to make the distinction.

Answer (score 1):

> I have been told to make a Satellite class,

```
class Satellite{};
```

> ...which is the parent class of the Moon and an artificial satellite.

```
class Moon: public Satellite{};

class ArtificialSatellite: public Satellite{};
```